# SQL creating a concatenated string of names from an array of ids

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I am developing reports using Streamtask with xReporter.  Recently, our databases were updated to allow for multiple projects to be assigned to a single task.  To achieve this, a string containing a a set of CSV index values was used to replace the old single index ie: '[1,2,3,4]' instead of 1.   As a result we now have to update a slew of reports.

To get around this, I replace the original selection statement:

```
(select prj.name from project_table prj where prj.id=t.project_id) as project,
```

with this line:

```
(select prj.name from project_table prj where prj.id = ANY((string_to_array(btrim(task_table.projects, '[]'), ','))::integer[])) as project,
```

which turns the string (successfully) into an array of integer values.

The problem is that I must be able to take this array of indices and retrieve each project name associated with each index, and concatenate them together into a string containing a list of the project names.

Because I have to implement this in an xReporter report, I believe I will need an SQL-only solution to my problem.

Comment: "*To achieve this, a string containing a a set of CSV index values was used*" - what **horrible** (really: horrible) design decision. Whoever decided that should be sentenced to maintain the integrity and correctness of that column in the future. And should do all reporting on it. You could have at least used a real array column which gives you the possibility of indexing and at least type safety.

Comment: Please fix your schema to save your sanity. See this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55871/postgresql-list-of-integers-separated-by-comma-or-integer-array-for-performance and this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17808/is-using-multiple-foreign-keys-separated-by-commas-wrong-and-if-so-why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing comma separated values in a relation database is a really horrible anti-pattern.

Postgres has some really nifty functions to workaround this design-error which makes the query actually quite easy (but probably not really fast)

```
select prj.name, tsk.id as task_id
from project_table prj
  join ( 
     select id, regexp_split_to_table(projects, ',')::int as pid
     from task_table
  ) tsk on tsk.pid = prj.id
order by prj.id
```

You original statement looks like you were really embedding that into a bigger statement, so I'm not sure how suitable the join is. But you could always create a normalized view on the mis-designed table using the above approach (the inner derived table).

Here is a SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6f9bb/1

Comment: Alright, well I havent gone to implement this yet, but after looking over the SQLFiddle page, it looks to be exactly what I need!   Thanks so much, a_horse.  I do agree the method they've chosen leaves them open to a lot of problems they could otherwise avoid by simply using an array of indices. Thats part of the reason I focused on finding a way to cast the csv string to an array before I worked with it. Unfortunately I've only been here a week, so I need to produce some working results before my opinion starts getting some more attention.  This should be a good start though.  Thanks!